# How to import datas from a Joomla 2.5 to a Joomla 3?

Tags: migration, community-builder

Community Builder is installed on a Joomla 2.5 website.

We are doing a new Joomla 3 website (no upgrade). We need to import users and parameters.

What is the best way to do that with Joomla ? Can we simply export and import required tables from database ?

Or do we need tu use an extension like SP Transfer ?

This question is related to Community Builder but it can be more general : how to safely export and import datas from a Joomla website to one other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I recommend you do is take a backup of your Joomla 2.5 site and on that backup, perform the migrations to Joomla 3.x.

Then install the latest version of Community Builder.

Once done, copy over the tables you require to your newly built Joomla 3.x site.

Comment: Thanks, it works, I post a detailed answer of the process

Answer (score 1):

To export/import your data from/to CB, you can try CBJuice :

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/extension-specific/community-builder-extensions/cbjuice

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Lodder's answer and some help from the [french Joomla forum](http://forum.joomla.fr/), this is what i’ve done :

- Make a backup of the Joomla 2.5
- Install the backup
- Upgrade to Joomla 3.x

**Copy the requrired tables :**

_comprofiler_xxx (All the table community builder)

_users

_usergroups

_user_usergroup_map

That's it !